# how to validate form before opening modelDialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-mvc

I want to validate all the form which controls required fills and after that I want to open a model dialog if the validation is successful. I can make the validation successfully but I am not able to write to code to open the modelDialog when the validation is successful. Do you know a way to fix that issue ? When I use formIsValid inside the function, it says unable to find the method. But , in the forums mostly formIsValid() is used. If you know any another way please let me know about the issue ? Thank you for your helps

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                                                onclick="if(formIsValid()) { $('#openModalModal').click();} ">Change Limit
                                    </button>
```

Comment: There is no generic javascript `formIsValid` function. Even if there was, it would require some reference to the form you want to validate. How do you normally determine that the form is valid?

Comment: hi Tomas. I normally use required inside <input type="number" such like              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputAmount"
                                               th:field="*{amount}" step=".01" required/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you're looking for is probably [`reportValidity()`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-form-checkvalidity). This is a method of the `HTMLFormElement` (`<form>`). Input fields typically have a `form` property that refers to the form they are in, so you'd do:

```
if(this.form.reportValidity()) { $('#openModalModal').click();}
```

Here's an example:

```js
const divResult = document.querySelector("div#validation");
function check() {
    const validity = this.form.reportValidity();
    divResult.classList.toggle("bad", !validity);
    divResult.classList.toggle("good", validity);
}
```

```css
div#validation span {
   display:none;
   font-weight: bold;
}
div#validation.good span.good {
   display:initial;
   color: green;
}
div#validation.bad span.bad {
   display:initial;
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
Text: <input type="test" required> 

<button type="button" onclick="check.call(this)">Check!</button>
</form>
<div id="validation"><span class="bad">BAD!</span><span class="good">GOOD :)</span></div>
```

Comment: @Tonyukuk "*When I click button now nothing hapens*" You mean the button in my answer, or on your website?

Comment: Possibly, you want to use `reportValidity`, which also displays the errors to the user.

Comment: that's working properly! Thank you Tomas. The only missing point is now I am not able to call the modalDialog .Is that snippet that you will see is enough to call the model dialog ? $('#changeBalanceModal').click();

Comment: thanks . i fixed it by caling $('#changeBalanceModal').modal('show'); thank you for precious helps